# How can I get the solutions of Minizinc when I run it from command line?

Tags: minizinc

I try to run minizinc from command line and limit the time , but I receive =====UNKNOWN===== as output after the time limit passed. When I run it from minizinc IDE it is able to found several solutions in ~10 seconds.

```
minizinc.exe --solver-time-limit 60000 --solver gecode Model.mzn data.dzn
```

How can I get the solutions when I am running from command line?

Answer (score 1):

Adding [-a option](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/command_line.html#options) will print all the intermediate solutions.

```
minizinc.exe -a --solver-time-limit 60000 --solver gecode Model.mzn data.dzn
```

Comment: This not the correct solution for the posed question. `-a` will indeed show all intermediate solutions, but even without this flag `minizinc` will output the bests solution so far when it reaches the timeout. It should not give the `=====UNKNOWN=====` status in this case.

Comment: that was not the case for me :(. Without the flag it gave =====UNKNOWN===== , with the flag I got a few solutions, same problem.

Comment: That sound like a bug in the solver to me. It would be great if you could file a bug report.

Comment: I tried with Chuffed, same result, where can I fill a bug report?

Comment: I filled a bug report on github.